# Is there a way to get all values currently in the registry

Tags: registry

i've been using `Mage::registry('current_category');` but i only found about that from a template done by someone else, so i am wondering if there is an easy way to get a list of all the registry keys/values currently being used in magento

while i'm not fussed if a link is provided with a list of magento ones i would like to get a list of any registry keys/values used in 3rd party modules

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sort of.

If you obey the intents of the Magento system designers, you can't see what's in the registry.  That's because Magento's core engineers have declared the array that stores the registry values on the `Mage` class as `private`

```
static private $_registry        = array();
```

Also, there's no method in `Mage` for fetching the raw registry or all its keys. This means under normal operating conditions, the only methods allowed to access `$_registry` are in the class `Mage`.  Since you can't rewrite anything in `Mage`, you're out of luck.

If you're willing to use reflection (and have PHP 5.3+ installed), you can use the following to grab the array

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('Mage');
$prop  = $class->getProperty('_registry');
$prop->setAccessible(true);        
$registry = $prop->getValue();
var_dump(  
    array_keys($registry)
);
```

This instantiates a `ReflectionClass` class, passing in `Mage` to tell PHP it's the defined `Mage` class we wish to reflect into.

Then we grab a ReflectionProperty object with `getProperty`, passing in `_registry` which tells PHP we want to reflect into the `_registry` property on the `Mage` class.

Then we use the `setAccessible` method to change the property from `private` to public, and then grab its value with `getValue`.

Comment: Plus one because Reflection. Reflect all the things.

Comment: ...and because Commercebug uses its fair share of reflection

Comment: @philwinkle Less than you'd think — just for the new events reporting in Commerce Bug 2, and only because there was no other way (if you want to see some real crimes against computer science, checkout Model/Events.php for my pre PHP 5.3 setAccessible support)

Comment: Great! ReflectionClass is pretty neat.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Unix you could do something like:

`grep -rni 'Mage::registry' app`

..to see all the occurrences of a registry value being set by anything in the app folder. Or you could be more specific and search in a specific module: `grep -rni 'Mage::registry' app/code/community/modulex`

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to check or debug something. To do this easly on main Mage class (app/Mage.php) change

```
static private $_registry = array();
```

to

```
static public $_registry = array();
```

And then you can access it anywhere.

```
foreach (Mage::$_registry as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried following: 
in `app/Mage.php` looking on function `public static function register()`

add

```
self::log($key);
```

And check file - `system.log`

Comment: Wrong. editing `Mage.php` is not encouraged. Also putting that log in that location will give you lot of headaches since the `system.log` will grow fast with registry log !!

Comment: Yes, but  this only for debug, not production