# How To Get Current Product ID in Model

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, model, tax

Im trying to retrieve the Current Product ID inside the Tax-model-Calculation.php (code in -> https://github.com/adam-paterson/magento-ce-1.9.0.1/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php )

```
public function calcTaxAmount($price, $taxRate, $priceIncludeTax = false, $round = true)
    {
        $taxRate = $taxRate / 100;
        if ($priceIncludeTax) {
            $amount = $price * (1 - 1 / (1 + $taxRate));
        } else {
            $amount = $price * $taxRate;
        }
        if ($round) {
            return $this->round($amount);
        }
        return $amount;
    }
```

I tried the following code:

```
public function calcTaxAmount($price, $taxRate, $priceIncludeTax=false, $round=true)
{
    $taxRate = $taxRate/100;
    $product = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
    var_dump($product);
```

but the following information is displayed in frontpage when I debug using var_dump($product):

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null

Additionally I tried `$product = $this->getProduct()->getId();`

with same result.

Comment: are you use tax cal model on product list page or product view page ?

Comment: hi @Abdul , calctaxamount is used in home, productlist, view and cart. thats the reason why I want to use current_product id inside the model.

Comment: If your need current product id in calcTaxAmount function then need to add one more argument in above function. If your wand then i will explain in details

Comment: hi @Abdul , yes please. Would be great!, thanks.

Comment: check ans and let me know if any queries :)

Comment: @Abdul thank you so much, read my comment please. thank you!

Comment: @Abdul created but, "you may award your bounty in 23hs.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow bellow steps:

**Step : 1** First copy core file from `app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Helper/Data.php` to local `app/code/local/Mage/Tax/Helper/Data.php` **or** override helper data

**After replace bellow functions**

```
public function getPrice($product, $price, $includingTax = null, $shippingAddress = null, $billingAddress = null,
                         $ctc = null, $store = null, $priceIncludesTax = null, $roundPrice = true)
{
    if (!$price) {
        return $price;
    }
    $store = $this->_app->getStore($store);
    if (!$this->needPriceConversion($store)) {
        return $store->roundPrice($price);
    }
    if (is_null($priceIncludesTax)) {
        $priceIncludesTax = $this->priceIncludesTax($store);
    }

    $percent = $product->getTaxPercent();
    $includingPercent = null;

    $taxClassId = $product->getTaxClassId();
    if (is_null($percent)) {
        if ($taxClassId) {
            $request = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')
                ->getRateRequest($shippingAddress, $billingAddress, $ctc, $store);
            $percent = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')
                ->getRate($request->setProductClassId($taxClassId));
        }
    }
    if ($taxClassId && $priceIncludesTax) {
        if ($this->isCrossBorderTradeEnabled($store)) {
            $includingPercent = $percent;
        } else {
            $request = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRateOriginRequest($store);
            $includingPercent = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')
                ->getRate($request->setProductClassId($taxClassId));
        }
    }

    if ($percent === false || is_null($percent)) {
        if ($priceIncludesTax && !$includingPercent) {
            return $price;
        }
    }

    $product->setTaxPercent($percent);
    if ($product->getAppliedRates() == null) {
        $request = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')
                ->getRateRequest($shippingAddress, $billingAddress, $ctc, $store);
        $request->setProductClassId($taxClassId);
        $appliedRates =  Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getAppliedRates($request);
        $product->setAppliedRates($appliedRates);
    }

    if (!is_null($includingTax)) {
        if ($priceIncludesTax) {
            if ($includingTax) {
                /**
                 * Recalculate price include tax in case of different rates.  Otherwise price remains the same.
                 */
                if ($includingPercent != $percent) {
                    // determine the customer's price that includes tax
                    $price = $this->_calculatePriceInclTax($price, $includingPercent, $percent, $store, $product);
                }
            } else {
                $price = $this->_calculatePrice($price, $includingPercent, false, false, $product);
            }
        } else {
            if ($includingTax) {
                $appliedRates = $product->getAppliedRates();
                if (count($appliedRates) > 1) {
                    $price = $this->_calculatePriceInclTaxWithMultipleRates($price, $appliedRates);
                } else {
                    $price = $this->_calculatePrice($price, $percent, true, false, $product);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ($priceIncludesTax) {
            switch ($this->getPriceDisplayType($store)) {
                case Mage_Tax_Model_Config::DISPLAY_TYPE_EXCLUDING_TAX:
                case Mage_Tax_Model_Config::DISPLAY_TYPE_BOTH:
                    if ($includingPercent != $percent) {
                        // determine the customer's price that includes tax
                        $taxablePrice = $this->_calculatePriceInclTax($price, $includingPercent, $percent, $store, $product);
                        // determine the customer's tax amount,
                        // round tax unless $roundPrice is set explicitly to false
                        $tax = $this->getCalculator()->calcTaxAmount($taxablePrice, $percent, true, $roundPrice, $product);
                        // determine the customer's price without taxes
                        $price = $taxablePrice - $tax;
                    } else {
                        //round tax first unless $roundPrice is set to false explicitly
                        $price = $this->_calculatePrice($price, $includingPercent, false, $roundPrice, $product);
                    }
                    break;

                case Mage_Tax_Model_Config::DISPLAY_TYPE_INCLUDING_TAX:
                    $price = $this->_calculatePrice($price, $includingPercent, false, false, $product);
                    $price = $this->_calculatePrice($price, $percent, true, false, $product);
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            switch ($this->getPriceDisplayType($store)) {
                case Mage_Tax_Model_Config::DISPLAY_TYPE_INCLUDING_TAX:
                    $appliedRates = $product->getAppliedRates();
                    if (count($appliedRates) > 1) {
                        $price = $this->_calculatePriceInclTaxWithMultipleRates($price, $appliedRates);
                    } else {
                        $price = $this->_calculatePrice($price, $percent, true, false, product);
                    }
                    break;

                case Mage_Tax_Model_Config::DISPLAY_TYPE_BOTH:
                case Mage_Tax_Model_Config::DISPLAY_TYPE_EXCLUDING_TAX:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    if ($roundPrice) {
        return $store->roundPrice($price);
    } else {
        return $price;
    }
}
```

''

```
protected function _calculatePriceInclTax($storePriceInclTax, $storePercent, $customerPercent, $store, $product=false)
{
    $priceExclTax         = $this->_calculatePrice($storePriceInclTax, $storePercent, false, false);
    $customerTax          = $this->getCalculator()->calcTaxAmount($priceExclTax, $customerPercent, false, false, $product);
    $customerPriceInclTax = $store->roundPrice($priceExclTax + $customerTax);
    return $customerPriceInclTax;
}
```

''

```
protected function _calculatePrice($price, $percent, $type, $roundTaxFirst = false, $product = false)
{
    $calculator = $this->getCalculator();
    if ($type) {
        $taxAmount = $calculator->calcTaxAmount($price, $percent, false, $roundTaxFirst, $product);
        return $price + $taxAmount;
    } else {
        $taxAmount = $calculator->calcTaxAmount($price, $percent, true, $roundTaxFirst, $product);
        return $price - $taxAmount;
    }
}
```

**Step : 2** After copy core file from `app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php` to local `app/code/local/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php` **or** override model file `Calculation.php`

and replace code from :

```
public function calcTaxAmount($price, $taxRate, $priceIncludeTax = false, $round = true)
{
    $taxRate = $taxRate / 100;

    if ($priceIncludeTax) {
        $amount = $price * (1 - 1 / (1 + $taxRate));
    } else {
        $amount = $price * $taxRate;
    }

    if ($round) {
        return $this->round($amount);
    }

    return $amount;
}
```

to

```
public function calcTaxAmount($price, $taxRate, $priceIncludeTax = false, $round = true, $product = false)
{
    if($product) {
    echo $product->getId();
    }

    $taxRate = $taxRate / 100;

    if ($priceIncludeTax) {
        $amount = $price * (1 - 1 / (1 + $taxRate));
    } else {
        $amount = $price * $taxRate;
    }

    if ($round) {
        return $this->round($amount);
    }

    return $amount;
}
```

Comment: what can I say! amazing. thank you so much. This post currently says "question eligible for bounty in 19 hours", I will not close the question so I can assign a bounty tomorrow and granted to you. once again, thank you!.

Answer (score 1):

Get a current product id in magento 1 by using below lines.

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$id = $product->getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get it using `Request` object:

> $productId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('product')

Which gives you requested product id inside `calcTaxAmount` method.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: hi @jayesh-patel thank you for the msg. I try that but I receive null for $productId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('product') when I var_dump the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method to get current register product id.

1. Just create a session to set the product id.You need to put below mentioned code in you `header.phtml` file.

   > $productId = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
   >        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCurrentProductId($productId);
2. Now you can get recently created session any where in Magento by using below code.

> Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCurrentProductId()

Hope it will help you. For more see  [Alan's answer here.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6670/is-there-a-way-to-get-all-values-currently-in-the-registry/6673#6673)

Comment: thanks @arunendra but I receive " Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null " placing that code in header.phtml